# How to use PathFilter correctly in go-git？

Tags: go, go-git

I am trying to analyze the **git commit log** by using **go-git**. But I encountered some problems and failed to solve them after many attempts.

In WSL(Ubuntu18.04), the command `root@(XXXXXXX/XXXXXX):.../www/docs/docs/gmaster# git log intro.mdx` will return 3 results like following text:

```
commit (commit hash)
Author: XXXXXX
Date:   Mon Oct 24 10:51:44 2022 +0800

    Feature/issues942

commit (commit hash)
Author: XXXXXX
Date:   Fri Oct 21 15:04:33 2022 +0800

    Feature/issues942

commit (commit hash)
Author: XXXXXX
Date:   Wed Sep 21 16:23:09 2022 +0800

    Merge branch 'master' into XXXX/XXXX
```

After reading the documents of **go-git**, I try to use the `LogOptions/PathFilter` to implement the `git log intro.mdx`.
Then I write code in windows/Goland like following:

```
r, _ := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), nil, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL: "D:\\project\\gmaster",
    })
    ref, _ := r.Head()
    cIter, _ := r.Log(&git.LogOptions{
        From:  ref.Hash(),
        Order: 4,
        PathFilter: func(s string) bool {
            s = "D:\\project\\gmaster\\www\\docs\\docs\\gmaster\\intro.mdx"
            _, err := os.Stat(s)
            if err != nil {
                return false
            }
            return true
        },
    })
    err := cIter.ForEach(func(c *object.Commit) error {
        fmt.Println(c)
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
```

Finally, the foregoing code will **return the whole commit log instead of 3 of the log**. It's really confused me.

Thanks in advance for your help.